# Compute the variance of $Z=g(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, variance

If $X,Y$ are two random variables, $g$ is a continuous function. In most books, we only discuss how to calculate the expected value of $g(X,Y)$.

My question: how to calculate the variance of $g(X,Y)$? Does the following relation hold?

$Var(g(X,Y))=E(g(X,Y)^2)–[E(g(X,Y)]^2$

Comment: The equality is true. $Z = g(X,Y)$ is just another random variable, so $\text{Var}(Z) = E[Z^2] - (E[Z])^2$ still holds.